# Use keyword in Apache ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, apache2

available folder, I want to use virtualhost functionality and rewrite rules. I have enable the rewrite rules using terminal. In this directory i have file expand-cq-paths file with below content :

```
<Macro ExpandCqPaths $path>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/$ $path.html [PT,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/campaigns
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/dam
    RewriteRule !^$path - [R=404,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ $path/$1 [PT,L]
</Macro>
```

And i have 000-default.conf file with below content :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/communique/dispatcher/cache
    ServerName geometrixx.com
    <Directory /var/www>
                AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
        SetHandler dispatcher-handler
    </IfModule>
    Use ExpandCqPaths /content/geometrixx/en
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    // for different locale
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *:80>
    // for different locale
</VirtualHost>
```

Issue is when i restart the web server, it gives me the error like :

```
H00526: Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'Use', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed
```

How can i solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use `Use` you need to have the [`macro`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_macro.html) module enabled, provided by [`libapache2-mod-macro`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-macro):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-macro
sudo a2enmod macro
sudo service apache2 restart
```